# OSM maps not rendering correctly after applying diffs

Tags: maps, gis, openstreetmap

I'm running a planet OSM server that became a couple months out of date. As such, I've been working to get it up to date using the planet daily diffs in conjunction with **osmosis**/**osm2pgsql**. And then I mark tiles as expired using **render_expired**. All of that seems to be working properly. However, when looking at the maps, there are significant pieces that aren't rendered such as roads and bodies of water. I can't post images yet but here's a link to an example

[http://i.imgur.com/qv41vEr.png](https://i.imgur.com/qv41vEr.png)

Comment: Did you miss some diffs?

Comment: Possibly. Am I able to just add the missing diffs or do I have to apply all the diffs starting from the missing one again?

Comment: I guess you have to start with the first diff again, otherwise this will lead to an inconsistent data base. But I have no experience with this.